# AES-256 encryption of a json file using Python

Tags: python, json, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a json file using AES-256 in python. Using the following code but having an error "TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable".

```
import json
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES


with open('filename.json','rb') as f:
    text=json.dumps(f)
key = 'QWE1ER2T3Y4U4I5O5PAD2SFH4JK3HX4Z'
IV= 'QWE1ER2T3Y4U4I5O'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), mode,IV=IV.encode('utf8'))
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
```

Json File:

```
{
  "user_id": "321871616",
  "name": "test",
  "phone_number": "9985623587",
  "token": "Bearer 4df8d0af-3b51-4c07-a9e1-b7cee519d169 ",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "data": {
    "launchPoint": "getMore",
    "journeyType": "prePurchase",
    "sourceURL": "https://www.google.com",
    "successRedirectURL": "https://www.fb.com",
    "productCode": "OPD",
    "customerType": "PP",
    "ppCustomerEligible": true,
    "ppBalance": 500.00,
    "appType": "native",
    "device": {
      "androidId": "s",
      "make": "qw",
      "firebaseId": "s",
      "advertisingId": "d",
      "installId": "d",
      "imei": "d",
      "model": "d",
      "deviceId": "d",
      "deviceType": "android",
      "os": {
        "osName": "1d2",
        "osVersion": "df",
        "appVersion": "df"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `json.loads(f)`

Comment: usong json.loads leads to below error "TypeError: Object type <class 'dict'> cannot be passed to C code"

Comment: Of course, you are loading json file into a dict, but you can't pass dictionary to `encrypt()`. If you don't need to perform any modifications on json file, you can just read it's content without serialization `text = f.read()`

Comment: it worked but I am getting some data like "
b'R\xb6/\x13\xc3\xb4c\xffE\x92\x93\xb8\xc0\xd2v.\x94\xd0\xf5\xcaIF"\x9c\xf9\x98\x17\xf8t\xd41\x19\xd8&\x81\xf6\x13l\x97\xa1]\x0c^\x11\x1c:\xf7\x1a\xa2@x\xdeg,t\xc6l\xca\x90a\xb9\xb1\x12W\x1661\xcf\xf9\xe7k\x83\x14(\xb2Hwqz\xfaR\xdeG\x05o\xacT|\x1dgm\xa5\x7f\x8d\x01\\a\'\xe0m?4\xeb\x9f\xbf\xe1\x82\xce\xf0UQ\x01\xc6s\xcf\xa6Y6\xbc\xe4\xc6\xb3\xd9\x90h\xcd\xa0>...." which is not correct.. Is there any mistake in my code? Using the online tool from the website "https://www.javainuse.com/aesgenerator" is providing me the correct encrypted response

Comment: output text format should be Base64 for my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to read the json file into a dict using json.loads.
Function `Cryptodome.Cipher.EcbMode.encrypt(self, plaintext, output=None)` requires bytes or bytearray as parameter `plaintext`, so it raised an error "TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable" when you passed a dict.
Just read the content of file as bytes and encrypt it:

```
import json
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
with open('filename.json','rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
key = 'QWE1ER2T3Y4U4I5O5PAD2SFH4JK3HX4Z'
IV= 'QWE1ER2T3Y4U4I5O'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), mode,IV=IV.encode('utf8'))

length = 16 - (len(text) % 16)
cbc_pad_text = text + bytes([length])*length # pad to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(cbc_pad_text)
```

Then we can print `ciphertext` as base64 format:

```
import base64
base64_ciphertext = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode("ascii")
print(base64_ciphertext)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the output I am getting after printing the ciphertext is like "b'R\xb6/\x13\xc3\xb4c\xffE\x92\x93\xb8\xc0\xd2v.\....." which is not correct. Using the online encryption website, I am getting output like "DMW7DeLQ0JIxGKjoMMHAQd868doxiQcwPEuSv7IIhsVmeOZWcDA8Yvg033mKm7t.." which is actually correct..Not sure where I need to change :( ..My output text format should be in Base64

Comment: I added the base64 output code in the answer.

Comment: excellent....many thanks